# Can't move graphics using graphics.py and pynput

Tags: python-3.x, graphics, pynput

I'm trying to move a single point in python using pynput but it does not move

I've tried making it so that `keyboard.press("W")` increases pointx and pointy by 10

```py
    from graphics import *
    from keyboard import *
    from pynput import *

    keyboard = keyboard.Controller()
    pointx = 250
    pointy = 250

    win = GraphWin("test", 500, 500)
    pt = Point(pointx, pointy)
    pt.draw(win)

    while keyboard.press("w"):
        pt.move(10, 10)
        pt.draw(win)
```

There are no error messages

Comment: Please actually ask a question in your post, otherwise you most likely won't get an answer :)

Comment: Also, your code is quite mixed up. `keyboard.Controller` is imported from `pynput`, its full name is `pynput.keyboard.Controller`. `from keyboard import *` is completely unused and can be removed. The `keyboard` package gets overwritten by creating a `keyboard` variable with the same name. And then, which is probably the real problem: `keyboard.press` does not *check* for key presses, it *generates* them.

Answer (score 1):

First thing straight away: The `pynput` and `keyboard` libraries do the same thing, so you only need to use one of them. As `keyboard` seems to need root rights on Linux, I suggest using `pynput`.

Don't use the same names twice. `keyboard` already is already a package, don't use it as a variable name.

`keyboard.Controller()` is meant for *controlling* the keyboard, not for reading it. What you were probably looking for is `keyboard.Listener`.

With `keyboard.Listener`, you cannot check for keys directly, instead you get a notification whenever a key gets pressed or released. Those notification(=callback) functions have to be given to `keyboard.Listener` in its constructor.
You can then either apply an action directly, whenever a key gets pressed, or you can track the current key state in a global variable, like this:

```
# The global dict that keeps track of the keyboard state
key_state = {}

# The function that gets called when a key gets pressed
def key_down(val):
    global key_state
    key_state[val] = True

# The function that gets called when a key gets released
def key_up(val):
    global key_state
    key_state[val] = False

# Initializes the keyboard listener and sets the functions 'key_down' and 'key_up'
# as callback functions
keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=key_down, on_release=key_up)
keyboard_listener.start()
```

We can then in our program check if a key got pressed with:

```
if key_state.get(keyboard.KeyCode(char='w')):
```

The entire program would look something like this:

```
from graphics import *
from pynput import *

import time


pointx = 250
pointy = 250

win = GraphWin("test", 500, 500)
pt = Point(pointx, pointy)
pt.draw(win)


# The global dict that keeps track of the state of 'w'
key_state = {}

# The function that gets called when a key gets pressed
def key_down(val):
    global key_state
    key_state[val] = True

# The function that gets called when a key gets released
def key_up(val):
    global key_state
    key_state[val] = False

# Initializes the keyboard listener and sets the functions 'key_down' and 'key_up'
# as callback functions
keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=key_down, on_release=key_up)
keyboard_listener.start()


# Continuously loop and update the window (important so it doesn't freeze)
while win.isOpen():
    win.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

    # Little bit of trickery: 
    # We combine the check if the key exists and if its value is 'true' in one
    # single operation, as both 'None' and 'False' are the same value for 'if'.
    if key_state.get(keyboard.KeyCode(char='w')):
        pt.move(10, 10)
```